# Files delete() method in Java is not working

Tags: java, file, path

Not able to delete the `file001.txt` which is created in my local dir path by using the `removeFile(s)` method in switch case. Then the method  `removeFile(s)` calls the class  `Employee_Remove`, where `file.delete()` method does not delete the files. Please find the below 2 codes and also screenshot.

I don't want to create duplicate or renaming the filename. I just need to delete the files which is created in my local dir. I did not understanding the problem whether it code problem or Eclipse problem.
Can anyone help to solve the issue.

[image]

```
case 3:
{
    System.out.print("\nPlease Enter Employee's ID :");
    String s=sc.nextLine();
    Employee_Remove epr =new Employee_Remove();
    epr.removeFile(s);
    break;
 }
```

---

```
class Employee_Remove {

    public void removeFile(String ID) {
        File file = new File("file" + ID + ".txt");
        if (file.exists()) {
            if (file.delete()) {
                System.out.println("\nEmployee has been removed Successfully");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("\nEmployee does not exists :( ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any output?

Comment: Looks to me like the file path is looking in the wrong directory.

Comment: Possible. Or eclipse just did not refresh the UI. Are the files still present in the file system?

Comment: Do you get any output? – 
no output, file is not deleting.

Comment: Possible. Or eclipse just did not refresh the UI. Are the files still present in the file system? i have refresh manually whenever executing the code. but no use , file is not deleting.

Answer (score 0):

If you get no output to the Eclipse console window, that means that:

1. Your application code has found the file.  If it didn't find it, you would get a message.
2. The file was not deleted.  If the delete had succeeded, then you would get a message to say so.

It is not clear why your application found the file but did not delete it deleted.  One possibility is that your application does not have permission to delete the file.  A second possibility is that something else has the file open.  On Windows that locks the file, and that would prevent the application from deleting it.  (There are some other more obscure causes, but I doubt that they would be applicable here ...)

If you want to get diagnostics that explain give more information about why the file wasn't deleted, switch to using the newer `java.nio.file.*` APIs; e.g. `java.nio.file.Files::delete(Path)`.

---

If the output is NOT as you described, then it is possible that the application DID delete the file (and said so) but Eclipse has not noticed.  In my experience Eclipse does not notice changes made to files that were not made by Eclipse itself.

If this is the case, then doing an Eclipse refresh should update the view.  The Eclipse shortcut for this is typically `F5` or `CNTRL-F5`, but check the key bindings.